# remove special character from .split string ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I read file using ruby and use .split to split line.

Example.txt

1

2

3

```
line1,line2,line3= @line.to_s.split("\n",3)
#actual
line1 => ["1
line2 => ", "2
line3 => ", "3"]
#what I expect
line1=1
line2=2
line3=3
```

how can i get what i expected?

Edit: it 's just 1 new line because I can't enter 1 new line in my question. To be more specific:

Example.txt

first_line\nsecond_line\nthird_line

```
File.open('Example.txt', 'r') do |f1|  
            @line = f1.readlines
            f1.close    
        end
line1,line2,line3= @line.to_s.split("\n",3)
    #actual
    line1 => ["first_line
    line2 => ", "second_line
    line3 => ", "third_line"]
    #what I expect
    line1=first_line
    line2=second_line
    line3=third_line
```

Comment: What is your input supposed to be? Three separate lines in a text file separated by a single new-line? What you're displaying is three lines separated with double-new-lines. How are you reading the file?

Comment: Where do the `[` and `]` come from? Those aren't in your input file nor are they in your code. As is, your question is missing a lot of needed information and needs much better clarification.

Comment: When I puts @line, it don't have [ ], I guess it come from '.split' and I don't know how to remove it althought I use .gsub

Comment: File.readlines 'Example.txt' is all you need, readlines would read the file into array of lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't split using `'\n'`, if you're trying to use line-ends. You *MUST* use `"\n"`.

Strings using `'\n'` do not interpret `\n` as a line-ending, instead, they treat it as a literal backslash followed by "n":

```
'\n' # => "\\n"
"\n" # => "\n"
```

---

The question isn't at all clear, nor is the input file example clear given the little example code presented, however, guessing at what you want from the desired result...

If the input is a file called 'example.txt' looking like:

```
1
2
3
```

You can read it numerous ways:

```
File.read('example.txt').split("\n")
# => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Or:

```
File.readlines('example.txt').map(&:chomp)
# => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Either of those work, however, there is a very bad precedence set when reading files into memory like this. It's called "slurping" and can crash your code or take it, and the machine it's running on, to a crawl if the file is larger than the available memory. And, even if it fits into memory, loading a huge file into memory can cause pauses as memory is allocated, and reallocated. So, don't do that.

Instead, read the file line-by-line and process it that way if at all possible:

```
File.foreach('example.txt') do |line|
  puts line
end
# >> 1
# >> 2
# >> 3
```

---

Don't do this:

```
File.open('Example.txt', 'r') do |f1|  
            @line = f1.readlines
            f1.close    
        end
```

Ruby will automatically close a file opened like this:

```
File.open('Example.txt', 'r') do |f1|
  ...
end
```

There is no need to use `close` inside the block.

Comment: It still have problem line1 => ["1

line2 => ", "2

line3 => ", "3"]
#what I expect

line1=1

line2=2

line3=3

Comment: Great, A BIG Thanks for all your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what exactly you're expecting (and what `@line` is). If you are looking for numbers you can use:

```
line1, line2, line3 = @line.to_s.scan(/\d/)
```

If you want other characters you can use some other regular expression.

Comment: It 's just example file, my file is more complicated than that.

Comment: What do you want to do, then? Can you give some more details?

Comment: I read the whole file with multiple line, then I use .split to get each line but it have special character in this -> ["  ,  " and I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: Use regexs to remove them. If those are the only characters you want to remove, you can try with ```@line.to_s.scan(/[^ \[\],\n]/)```.